# How to install/use older version of Qt

Tags: qt

I'm building a project that relay on open source program that was created long time ago using an old version of Qt (V3.3).

Is there anyway to install the older version? or upgrading the program?

Answer (score 1):

Current and older versions of Qt along with installation instructions are available [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/).