# Downgrade from 22.04 to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 21.10, 22.04, downgrade

It seems that Qt 6.3 and some PHP plugins are not usable under Ubuntu 22.04.
Is there a way to downgrade to 21.10 (where I came from) ?

I searched in the Update manager but I found nothing about.
Looking on the Internet most of sources just suggest to reinstall everything from scratch.

But I don't think there is no way just to undo an upgrade!

Comment: if you need help investigating the php issues + qt 6.3  post a new question with as much detail as possible

Comment: @Rinzwind: already done, i.e.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407533/microsoft-odbc-v18-is-not-find-by-apt

Comment: I want to downgrade too. My Wifi and a working cifs mount to older Timecapsule were killed of by upgrading.

Comment: If you're talking about a desktop release; you can *upgrade via re-install* or just re-install an existing Ubuntu desktop release (including *flavors*) and use this to change release.  I'm involved in QA-testing, and often perform this, we currently have *dailies* for 20.04, 22.04 & *kinetic* (what will be 22.10 on release), meaning I can make the existing install whichever I install & I verify that my data remains, and *manually installed* packages are auto-reinstalled... There are complications if using 3rd party apps, even specific apps (when going backwards) - but I'm doing this very often

Comment: @guiverc since I'm working on a remote (desktop) machine, i cannot easily reinstall. I hoped there is something like dist "downgrade"

Comment: Ubuntu (/Debian) package tools are designed for upgrading only, so any downgrades are options you've pre-prepared via selection of file-system that allows *snapshots* to be restored, or other backup strategy.  You'll know which of those you'll have put into practice more than we will.

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing unless you created it yourself (ie. made a full system backup).

The current options are:

- Either fix the issue yourself, file a bugreport and wait for a fix. A fix could be to install an older QT in 22.04 [How to install/use older version of Qt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864073/how-to-install-use-older-version-of-qt) points to a [list of older versions](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/). [how to install or revert to an older version of Qt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912365/how-to-install-or-revert-to-an-older-version-of-qt) is a bit more informative.
- Install 21.10.

A suggestion: when installing create a post install script with all your manual alterations (installing, removing software, changed gconf settings, make a backup osf file you edit to a safe location so you can copy it back into the system) so you can execute this script after every install. One time a bit of work but very useful in the long run.